# Extract data from XML and pass to data.frame (use NA for missing)

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I've got an XML file that I want to extract data from. So far I've managed to do everything with the tidyverse and xml2 packages, but I cannot figure out how to solve the next riddle in my XML quest.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:ArchiveView>
    <Notification ID="1001">
        <persons>
            <Timestamp>07:39:25</Timestamp>
            <person type="A" name="Barney">
                <uniqueUserId>2222</uniqueUserId>
            </person>
        </persons>
        <persons>
            <Timestamp>08:40:25</Timestamp>
            <person type="B" name="John">
                <uniqueUserId>1111</uniqueUserId>
            </person>
        </persons>
    </Notification>
    <Notification ID="1002">
        <persons>
            <Timestamp>14:39:25</Timestamp>
            <person type="A" name="Barney">
                <uniqueUserId>2222</uniqueUserId>
            </person>
        </persons>
    </Notification>
    <Notification ID="1003">
    </Notification>
</ns2:ArchiveView>
```

Since the maximum number of persons that can be assigned to a Notification is 3, I would like to end up with a data.frame that looks like this:

```
ID    name1    time1     type1    name2    time2     type2    name3    time3     type3
1001  Barney   07:39:25  A        John     08:40:25  B        NA       NA        NA
1002  Barney   14:39:25  A        NA       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA
1003  NA       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA
```

What I've managed to get so far:

```
doc <- read_xml( "./data/test.xml" )
```

extract all ID

```
df.ID <- data.frame( 
           ID = xml_find_all( doc, ".//Notifications" ) %>% xml_attrs() %>%  unlist() , 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Identify the ID's of notifications that have persons attached

```
ID.with.persons <- xml_find_all( doc, ".//Notifications[ persons ]" ) %>% 
                   xml_attrs() %>% 
                   unlist()
```

Create a nodeset of notifications with persons attached

```
nodes.persons <- xml_find_all( doc, ".//Notifications[ persons ]"
```

I've also managed to get all names of the persons (in one vector)

```
persons.name <- nodes.persons %>% xml_attr("name") %>% unlist()
```

I've got the feeling I'm pretty close to the solution, but I cannot wrap my mind around how to merge all this data into one nice data.frame (as described above).

All suggestions are warmly appreciated :)

Comment: This is not a valid XML since the namespace prefix, *ns2*, is never assigned. Please post full root or actual XML sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very workmanlike approach (I'm pretty new to R, so it's probably not very R-like.) Just loop through each element, sticking your desired elements into a vector. Transform it into a matrix at the end and plug it into a dataframe. This only works because there are a fixed number of columns to build the matrix with.

```
library(xml2)
doc <- read_xml("test.xml")
row <- c()
notifications <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//Notification")
for (i in 1:length(notifications)) {
    row <- c(row, xml_attr(notifications[i], "ID"))
    for (j in 1:3) {
        person <- xml_find_all(notifications[i], sprintf("persons[%d]", j))
        if (length(person) > 0) {
            row <- c(row, xml_find_chr(person, "string(./person/@name)"))
            row <- c(row, xml_find_chr(person, "string(./Timestamp/text())"))
            row <- c(row, xml_find_chr(person, "string(./person/@type)"))
        } else {
            row <- c(row, NA, NA, NA)
        }
    }
}
df <- data.frame(matrix(data=rows, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE))
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "name1", "time1", "type1", "name2", "time2", "type2", "name3", "time3", "type3")
df
```

---

Output:

```
    ID  name1    time1 type1 name2    time2 type2 name3 time3 type3
1 1001 Barney 07:39:25     A  John 08:40:25     B  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2 1002 Barney 14:39:25     A  <NA>     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3 1003   <NA>     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution.  It has more manually coding than I would like but it does show the solution technique:

```
library(xml2)
doc<-read_xml("*Your xml Document goes here*")

#find the Notification nodes
Notices<-xml_find_all( doc, ".//Notification" )

#find all of the timestamps in each Notification
timestamps<-sapply(Notices, function(x){xml_text(xml_find_all(x, ".//Timestamp"))})

#extract the three timestamps in each Notification (missing ones return NA)
#sapply returns a column, need to transpose to create the row in the data frame
time.df<-data.frame(t(sapply(timestamps, function(x){c(x[1], x[2], x[3])})))
#rename the column names
names(time.df)<-paste0("time", 1:3)

#repeat for the person's name and type
persons.name <-sapply(Notices, function(x){x %>% xml_find_all(  ".//person" ) %>% xml_attr("name")})
name.df<-data.frame(t(sapply(persons.name, function(x){c(x[1], x[2], x[3])})))
names(name.df)<-paste0("name", 1:3)

persons.type <-sapply(Notices, function(x){x %>% xml_find_all(  ".//person" ) %>% xml_attr("type")})
type.df<-data.frame(t(sapply(persons.type, function(x){c(x[1], x[2], x[3])})))
names(type.df)<-paste0("type", 1:3)

#assemble the final answer and rearrange the column order
answer<-cbind(name.df, time.df, type.df)
answer<-answer[,c(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9)]

df.ID <- data.frame(ID = xml_find_all( doc, ".//Notification" ) %>%  
        xml_attr("ID"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
answer<-cbind(df.ID, answer)
```

The code's comments explain the steps taken for the solution.  I sure there is some optimization possible but it is a good start.